# Memory leak by tomcat starting a thread on undeploy

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, memory-leaks

I get a warning from tomcat about

> A web application appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned
>   connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very
>   likely to create a memory leak.

This is a known-problem which I solved by calling

```
com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown();
```

in `MyServler.destroy()`. This works fine, except for servlets which were never used. For such servlets, neither `init` not `destroy` get ever called. However, the `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread` gets started! By modifying its source, I could find out where:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.start(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:19)
com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:106)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:510)
java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:490)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:490)
java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.loader.JdbcLeakPrevention.clearJdbcDriverRegistrations(JdbcLeakPrevention.java:45)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferencesJdbc(WebappClassLoader.java:1775)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferences(WebappClassLoader.java:1704)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.stop(WebappClassLoader.java:1622)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stop(WebappLoader.java:710)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4649)
org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.undeploy(ManagerServlet.java:1365)
org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.undeploy(HTMLManagerServlet.java:563)
org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:123)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In the stacktrace there's no trace of my code, so I wonder how can I prevent it? Alternatively, how can I shut down the thread without `MyServlet.destroy()` being called?

The above stacktrace is from tomcat6, but tomcat7 leaks as well.

Comment: Can you not register a `ServletContextListener` to be notified of when the web app (rather than an individual servlet) is unloaded?

Comment: @biziclop I guess, I can. However, I have no idea how to reach my servlet ot the culprit thread from the `ServletContext`.

Comment: Why do you need to reach the servlet? Does the `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown()` only work from a servlet? Or am I misreading something?

Comment: @biziclop It's a static method belonging to a class *loaded by the servlet's classloader*. So I need something like `getTheRightClassLoader().loadClass("com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread")`. Maybe `servletContextEvent.getClass().getClassLoader()` would do, maybe not. Maybe I'm missing something. I'll try the `ServletContextListener`, unless given a simpler solution.

Comment: @maartinus Unless I'm badly mistaken, the class loader belongs to the web app, and therefore all servlets are loaded by the same class loader as the servlet context listener. Things would be pretty unworkable if that wasn't the case.

Comment: @biziclop I'm rather clueless here, so let's assume, you're right. According to the link given [in the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35202632/581205), it should work. Still, it's pretty ugly... starting something on undeploy and then hunting it down.

Comment: @biziclop I'm pretty confused about the difference between a "web app" and a "servlet". Could you elaborate?

Comment: Simply put: a web app is all the stuff you put in a single WAR file. It can contain servlets, filters, listeners, static resources, JSP files, and it will always contain exactly one `web.xml` file, where you can define how all this fits together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, by all means, doesn't seem to be a problem with your code.

It seems that it's something known elsewhere... Check these links that came up from a google search:
https://techblog.ralph-schuster.eu/2014/07/09/solution-to-tomcat-cant-stop-an-abandoned-connection-cleanup-thread/comment-page-1/

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68556

Comment: It works. It's ugly as now in `MyServletContextListener.contextDestroyed` the thread gets both started and shut down.